# Configuring IO18, IO19 for I2C connectivity on Intel Edison Kit for Arduino

Tags: i2c, edison

[Intel Edison Kit for Arduino Hardware Guide](http://download.intel.com/support/edison/sb/edisonarduino_hg_331191008.pdf) instructs:

```
echo 28 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo 27 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo 204 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo 205 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo 236 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo 237 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo 14 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo 165 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo 212 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo 213 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo 214 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo low > /sys/class/gpio/gpio214/direction
echo high > /sys/class/gpio/gpio204/direction
echo high > /sys/class/gpio/gpio205/direction
echo in > /sys/class/gpio/gpio14/direction
echo in > /sys/class/gpio/gpio165/direction
echo low > /sys/class/gpio/gpio236/direction
echo low > /sys/class/gpio/gpio237/direction
echo in > /sys/class/gpio/gpio212/direction
echo in > /sys/class/gpio/gpio213/direction
echo mode1 > /sys/kernel/debug/gpio_debug/gpio28/current_pinmux
echo mode1 > /sys/kernel/debug/gpio_debug/gpio27/current_pinmux
echo high > /sys/class/gpio/gpio214/direction
```

However line 3 already gives an error:

```
echo: write error: No such device
```

Any suggestions on how to enable I2C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a strange problem which we were not able to resolve in an acceptable manner after all.

The problem disappeared after we re-flashed the device.